# Open Terminal failed with osascript after electron-packager

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, electron, osascript

When I try to execute an osascript command under my Electron project, it works under dev mode(1), but after building it with electron-packager(2) and executing the binary file, an error appears.

1. It works with this execution command to debug:
   `# electron .`
2. It fails with this compilation command to package the project:
   `# electron-packager . MyProject --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=1.3.5 --overwrite`

This is the source code:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var script = "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"' -e 'set newTab to do script' -e 'end tell'";

childProcess.exec(script, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Console displays this error:

```
stdout: 
stderr: 45:51: syntax error: Expected end of line but found “script”. (-2741)
exec error: Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'set newTab to do script' -e 'end tell'
45:51: syntax error: Expected end of line but found “script”. (-2741)
```

**BUT**

The same source code works after packager if the script variable is equal to:

```
var script = "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'get volume settings'";
```

**My Env**

My node version: v4.5.0

My electron version: v1.3.5

Comment: It is not something to tell Terminal, it is just `osascript -e 'get volume settings'`

Comment: Oops, I updated it. Thank you.